With Python create a Google Cloud Instance Template with latest Ubuntu OS
I want to create a Google Cloud Instance Template with the latest Ubuntu OS.
I get this error:

google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xyz/global/instanceTemplates: The resource 'projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-2204-lts' was not found

What should I change in my code to use the latest Ubuntu OS? I guess it is something with this tuple:
initialize_params.source_image = ("projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-2204-lts")

create_template():
from __future__ import annotations

import sys
from typing import Any

import google
from google.api_core.extended_operation import ExtendedOperation
from google.cloud import compute_v1

from src.routes.run_fw_engagements.c_instance_template.wait_for_extended_operation import wait_for_extended_operation


def create_template(project_id: str, template_name: str) -> compute_v1.InstanceTemplate:
    """
    Create a new instance template with the provided name and a specific
    instance configuration.

    Args:
        project_id: project ID or project number of the Cloud project you use.
        template_name: name of the new template to create.

    Returns:
        InstanceTemplate object that represents the new instance template.
    """
    # The template describes the size and source image of the boot disk
    # to attach to the instance.
    disk = compute_v1.AttachedDisk()
    initialize_params = compute_v1.AttachedDiskInitializeParams()
    initialize_params.source_image = (
        "projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-2204-lts"
    )
    initialize_params.disk_size_gb = 10
    disk.initialize_params = initialize_params
    disk.auto_delete = True
    disk.boot = True

    # The template connects the instance to the `default` network,
    # without specifying a subnetwork.
    network_interface = compute_v1.NetworkInterface()
    network_interface.name = "global/networks/default"

    # The template lets the instance use an external IP address.
    access_config = compute_v1.AccessConfig()
    access_config.name = "External NAT"
    access_config.type_ = "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
    access_config.network_tier = "PREMIUM"
    network_interface.access_configs = [access_config]

    template = compute_v1.InstanceTemplate()
    template.name = template_name
    template.properties.disks = [disk]
    template.properties.machine_type = "e2-micro"
    template.properties.network_interfaces = [network_interface]

    template_client = compute_v1.InstanceTemplatesClient()
    operation = template_client.insert(
        project=project_id, instance_template_resource=template
    )

    wait_for_extended_operation(operation, "instance template creation")

    response: google.cloud.compute_v1.types.compute.InstanceTemplate = template_client.get(project=project_id, instance_template=template_name)

    # Map the response to variables
    instance_template_id = response.id
    instance_template_kind = response.kind
    instance_template_name = response.name
    creation_timestamp = response.creation_timestamp
    description = response.description
    self_link = response.self_link
    machine_type = response.properties.machine_type

    # Accessing network interfaces
    network_interface = response.properties.network_interfaces[0]
    network_name = network_interface.name
    access_config = network_interface.access_configs[0]
    access_config_name = access_config.name
    access_config_type = access_config.type_
    access_config_network_tier = access_config.network_tier

    # Accessing disks
    disk = response.properties.disks[0]
    disk_device_name = disk.device_name
    disk_boot = disk.boot
    disk_type = disk.type_
    disk_source_image = disk.initialize_params.source_image
    disk_size_gb = disk.initialize_params.disk_size_gb

    # Print the extracted variables
    print("Instance Template ID:", instance_template_id)
    print("Kind:", instance_template_kind)
    print("Name:", instance_template_name)
    print("Creation Timestamp:", creation_timestamp)
    print("Description:", description)
    print("Self Link:", self_link)
    print("Machine Type:", machine_type)
    print("Network Interface Name:", network_name)
    print("Access Config Name:", access_config_name)
    print("Access Config Type:", access_config_type)
    print("Access Config Network Tier:", access_config_network_tier)
    print("Disk Device Name:", disk_device_name)
    print("Disk Boot:", disk_boot)
    print("Disk Type:", disk_type)
    print("Disk Source Image:", disk_source_image)
    print("Disk Size (GB):", disk_size_gb)

    # Return response
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_template(project_id="xyz", template_name="template-test-6")

wait_for_extended_operation():
from __future__ import annotations

import sys
from typing import Any

from google.api_core.extended_operation import ExtendedOperation
from google.cloud import compute_v1


def wait_for_extended_operation(
    operation: ExtendedOperation, verbose_name: str = "operation", timeout: int = 300
) -> Any:
    """
    Waits for the extended (long-running) operation to complete.

    If the operation is successful, it will return its result.
    If the operation ends with an error, an exception will be raised.
    If there were any warnings during the execution of the operation
    they will be printed to sys.stderr.

    Args:
        operation: a long-running operation you want to wait on.
        verbose_name: (optional) a more verbose name of the operation,
            used only during error and warning reporting.
        timeout: how long (in seconds) to wait for operation to finish.
            If None, wait indefinitely.

    Returns:
        Whatever the operation.result() returns.

    Raises:
        This method will raise the exception received from `operation.exception()`
        or RuntimeError if there is no exception set, but there is an `error_code`
        set for the `operation`.

        In case of an operation taking longer than `timeout` seconds to complete,
        a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` will be raised.
    """
    result = operation.result(timeout=timeout)

    if operation.error_code:
        print(
            f"Error during {verbose_name}: [Code: {operation.error_code}]: {operation.error_message}",
            file=sys.stderr,
            flush=True,
        )
        print(f"Operation ID: {operation.name}", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
        raise operation.exception() or RuntimeError(operation.error_message)

    if operation.warnings:
        print(f"Warnings during {verbose_name}:\n", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
        for warning in operation.warnings:
            print(f" - {warning.code}: {warning.message}", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)

    return result



